# как сделать выборку нескольких элементов из массива и добавлять им класс, а у остальных убирать?

Tags: javascript, html

делаю слайдер. 
допустим есть массив и мне нужно добавлять через цикл нескольким его элементам какой-либо класс.

я делаю так:

```
for(let i=0; i<example.length; i+=2){...}
```

вообщем, должно работать примерно так:

(выделенным элементам массива добавляется класс, у остальных его быть не должно)

[**1**,**2**,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

*клик на кнопку *

[1,2,**3**,**4**,5,6,7,8,9,10]

*ещё один клик *

[1,2,3,4,**5**,**6**,7,8,9,10]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('div')
let counter = 0

addEventListener('click', function() {
  for(let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList.remove('green')
    
    els[counter].classList.add('green')
    els[counter + 1] && els[counter + 1].classList.add('green')
  }
  
  counter+=2
  counter = counter % 10
})
```

```css
body {
  user-select: none;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```